# How to check if a word matches to bulk of words in text file?

Tags: c#

I already used this code, but it takes much more time to search bulk data. My text file contains more than a million words, but all words are in alphabetical order. How to search the words in a dictionary manner.

```
int aCounter = 0; string aWordInTextFile;
// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Rider\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Resources\enable3.txt");
while((aWordInTextFile = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine (aWordInTextFile);
    if(textBox1.Text == aWordInTextFile){
        MessageBox.Show("String Match, found a string in notepad file");
        break;
    }
    aCounter++;
    Console.ReadLine();

}

file.Close();
```

Comment: @wooters: You changed the description of the contents of the file from 1.000.000 words to 10 words...

Comment: @Guffa I'm sorry. I should have Googled lakh. I thought it was a grammatical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the words are sorted, you can use binary search to do the searching part fast:

```
string[] words = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Rider\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Resources\enable3.txt");
int index = Array.BinarySearch(words, textBox1.Text);
if (index >= 0) {
  MessageBox.Show("String Match, found a string in notepad file");
}
```

However, this approach is only better if you read the file once, and do multiple searches in the data. If you only do one search, then what you have is as good as any reasonably simple solution can be.

Side note: The file that you have is normally referred to as a *text file*. The Notepad program is just one of many programs that can edit text files.

Comment: Personally I think  "search the words in a dictionary manner" would map better to `words.ToDictionary(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`, but binary search is not bad too.

Comment: hai i entered the word apple it is in the 7538 location. but is returs a value of -7538 to index. so that the if condition fails and not enters in to the block. what i have to do now. plzz help @guffa

Comment: @Rajsekharpakalapati: A negative value means that the word wasn't found in the file. Investigate why the word didn't match to find out what you need to do. If for example the case of the strings doesn't match, then you would need to use an overload of the `BinarySearch` method that takes an `IComparer`.

Comment: the word apple is there in my words list.i put a break point and see the valves.....and the values are like this...which is mention in breackets...      int index(-7538) = Array.BinarySearch(words(172823), textBox1.Text(apple)); initially the word is in 7538 after it goes to  = it is changing as -7538 please help @Guffa

Comment: @Rajsekharpakalapati: A negative value means that the word wasn't found in the file. Either it's actually not a match, or the words aren't sorted properly, You should check what you get from `textBox1.Text == words[7538]`.

Comment: I checked this condition if(textBox1.text==words[7538]){messageBox.show("word matched")} and the condition is true. @Guffa

Comment: hae in the code which you  have enter .readallLines and .binarySearch is in blue colour but when i typing i got that in black color.......i think the miss behaviour of the code is because of that only...suggest me y i am getting like that and rectify it. @Guffa

Comment: @Rajsekharpakalapati: The it looks like the words are not actually sorted, at least not with the same comparison as the binary search uses. The color coding in SO (Google Prettify) and Visual Studio is different. Prettify tries to spot classes and identifiers based on casing, it doesn't even know what language it is, while Visual Studio knows what everything is and can color code it exactly.

Comment: can you post the code in other method to reach my validation. @Guffa

Comment: i mean another logic to reach my validation. @Guffa

Comment: @Rajsekharpakalapati: You can use a hash set: `bool exists = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Rider\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Resources\enable3.txt")).ContansKey(textBox1.Text);`